# CD tray won't open after accidentally stopping Brasero CD burn

Tags: cd, burning, cd-drive, brasero

My laptop is an HP Pavilion g6, running Xubuntu 14.04. I was burning a CD, but accidentally pressed the spacebar. Brasero immediately stopped burning, now I can't open the CD tray anymore. I've tried ejecting using the hardware button, in Nautilus, and using the terminal eject command — nothing worked. What should I do?

Output of *sudo eject /dev/sr0*:

```
eject: kon niet uitwerpen, laatste fout: Ongepaste ioctl() voor apparaat
```

Output of *sudo file /dev/sr0*:

```
/dev/sr0: block special
```

Output of *sudo eject -i off*:

```
eject: kon apparaat niet openen of vinden voor: `cdrom'
```

(The language is Dutch by the way, would you have to translate.)

Answer (score 1):

Most optical drives have an emergency eject hole that you can push a straightened paper clip into to push the release lever, opening the tray. [image: cd-eject]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use Brasero. Brasero is a buggy application.

Use k3b, which can be installed by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

If you don't want all the kde dependencies, use xfburn. Which is installed with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xfburn
```

Now for the issue at hand.

1. Make sure you don't have a file browser opening looking at the CD
2. Make sure brasero isn't still trying to access the CD
3. If that doesn't work, get a small pin and try pressing the button in the small hole found on the front of the drive.

Comment: A file browser nor Brasero are open. I see one little hole, but getting something in that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try these commands in the terminal?: 1. 'sudo eject /dev/sr0' 2. 'file /dev/sr0' 3. 'sudo eject -i off'

Comment: Added the outputs of those to my question; the drive still isn't open.

Comment: Did you make sure to sudo all the commands? Or did you just not include the sudo in your edit?

Comment: I didn't use sudo for the second one, tried it again with sudo now, still doesn't work. The others were sudoed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got it working. I got the CD tray open when the laptop was just on, before Ubuntu launched. Now everything works fine again.